# @TestPropertySource is not helping to fetch configuration property values

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5

In the following test code snippet, values of number_of_days.last and number_of_months.plan are not getting fetched from the configuration file.Please check and see what could be the reason.When i remove @Value annotation from my service class ShiftPlanService.java and just initialize the values there with the required values,the test passes.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=SpringbootMysqlExampleApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="src/main/resources/application.properties",properties= {"number_of_days.last= 7","number_of_months.plan= 2"})
class ShiftPlanServiceTest {
        @Mock
        ShiftPlanRepo mockedSpr;
    
        @Mock(lenient = true)
        ShiftDetailsRepo mockedSdr;
    
        @Mock(lenient = true)
        EmployeeDetailsRepo mockedEdr;
    
        @Spy
        ShiftPlanService sps;
    
        @BeforeEach
        public void setUp() {
            when(mockedSdr.findShiftNameById(1)).thenReturn("Morning");
            when(mockedSdr.findShiftNameById(2)).thenReturn("Afternoon");
            when(mockedEdr.getNameById(0)).thenReturn("Amit");
            when(mockedEdr.getNameById(1)).thenReturn("Anupam");
            when(mockedEdr.getNameById(2)).thenReturn("Chirag");
            when(mockedEdr.getNameById(3)).thenReturn("Rashmi");
            when(mockedEdr.count()).thenReturn(4L);
        }
    
        @Test
        public void testCreateShiftPlan() {
            sps.createShiftPlan(4, 1, 2020);
            verify(mockedSpr, times(36)).save(any(ShiftPlan.class));
            verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockedSpr);
        }
   }
```

application.properties file is as follows-

```
server.port=8104
number_of_days.last= 7
number_of_months.plan= 2
spring.datasource.url=<<sensitive info>>
spring.datasource.username=<sensitive info>
spring.datasource.password=<sensitive info>

#Keep the connection alive while idle for a long time
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle= true
spring.datasource.validationQuery= SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

In the ShiftPlanService class, i have

```
@Value("${number_of_days.last}")
public int ndl;

@Value("${number_of_months.plan}")
public int nm;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are intending to use a real instance of ShiftPlanService and have mocks injected. You need to have Spring autowire the ShiftPlanService into your test and tell it to inject the mocks like this:

```
@Autowired
@InjectMocks
ShiftPlanService sps;
```

Though you may consider just instantiating ShiftPlanService yourself in your setup method and just pass your mocks and set the other properties on the ShiftPlanService instead.

Comment: Hi,@SpyBean ShiftPlanService sps; didn't work. I am getting null pointer exception after doing that, at the line sps.createShiftPlan(4, 1, 2020);

Comment: I reread your question and I think the issue is related to Spring not autowiring in your mocks. You shouldn't need to use a spy for this since you aren't doing any spying the ShiftPlanService.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing Mockito injection with Spring injection. `@Value` is a Spring concept and will only be injected when Spring manages the bean, but the instance of `ShiftPlanService` you have in your test is injected by `Mockito` using `@Spy` (which as has been pointed out you don't really need).

My recommendation would be to decide what you want - a unit test with mocks, or a full-blown Spring test with the application context running. It seems to me that your intent is to write a unit test with everything mocked out, in which case:

- remove `@ContextConfiguration` and `@TestPropertySource` (you don't need those for unit tests)
- use `@InjectMocks` instead of `@Spy` on `ShiftPlanService sps` - it will most likely do what you want, depending on how `ShiftPlanService` is implemented
- manually set the config values you need in `sps`; you can add setters for those for the test to use; if the unit test is in the same package as the class - which is a good practice - they can be package-private too - because in production Spring will autowire them for you, so you only need them for the test
- oh, and keep the `@Value` annotation in your `ShiftPlanService` - it's needed for production - as explained above

Comment: Hi @Dariusz, i have the following doubts-                                                                 
1. where do i add those setters, in the test class or in the ShiftPlanService class?  2. being in the same package means if ShiftPlanService is in src/main/java/ com.example.springboot.shift.planner.service and the test class is in src/test/java/com.example.springboot.shift.planner.service, are they in same package?

Comment: (1) in `ShitfPlanService`, and you call them in the test to set the values you need in the test (2) yes, that is (IMO) a good practice for _unit_ tests (component/integration tests where you start up Spring are a separate class of tests and usually live in separate package or even module). The benefit is that you easily know where to find corresponding test for your production class and can access package-private (non-public) methods/constructors if necessary for the test, which are still hidden from API clients

Comment: ref (2) again, your _source root_ (src/main/java vs src/test/java) doesn't matter in Java once compiled, the classes are still considered to be in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

We invented a Mockito extension that allows for easy injection of String/Integer/Boolean properties. Checkout the readme, it's super easy to use and works along with `@InjectMocks`

https://github.com/exabrial/mockito-object-injection

Comment: How is this different than the `@InjectMocks` that the Mockito library already provides?

Comment: `@InjectMocks` can't inject Strings, Integers, Booleans, etc. This extension works alongside `@InjectMocks` to allow for this.